# Removing filters from where condition

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a WHERE condition that is generated dynamically via PHP. This is a sample of a WHERE section of the query

```
WHERE 1=1 AND (`CATEGORYID`='A1') AND (`BRAND`=:filter_0 OR `BRAND`=:filter_1) 
AND (`KEYWORDS` LIKE :keyword_2) 
AND `TYPE` = '0' AND `DISTRICT`='1' ORDER BY `STARTDAY` DESC
```

Can anyone suggest a way to remove a certain sections of the WHERE clause eg: Remove the BRAND section from the SQL.

Comment: str_replace needs to match the exact phrase. But the words BRAND and filter_0 will change dynamically.

Comment: How is the where clause generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the PHP always maintains that output:

```
Match:               Replace:
AND \(`BRAND`.*?\)   <nothing>
```

This regex looks for the start of another AND starting with (`BRAND` with a lazy search for the nearest closing parenthesis.

In PHP, I believe you would do this:

```
preg_replace ( "AND \(`BRAND`.*?\)" , '' , $string);
```

where preg_replace takes the arguments (find, replace, original).

Comment: Thanks this worked. needed two starting and ending slashes like preg_replace ( "/AND \(`BRAND`.*?\)/i" , '' , $string)